# How to test a sentry exception was called in Laravel using Pest?

Tags: php, laravel, testing, mocking

I am trying to test an laravel app, I have this code:

```
$this->reportable(function (Throwable $e) {
            if (
                app()->bound('sentry') && config('app.env') === 'production'
                )
            ) {
                app('sentry')->captureException($e);
            }
        });
```

the code is working but I would like to know how to test it, I would like to test if the captureException method was called using Pest or phpunit

Comment: Open tinker and throw new \Exception() . Or php artisan sentry:test

Comment: testing using phpunit or pest

Comment: Mock sentry, throw exception, check.